# Convert text file to input format of PrefixSpan to use in Spark Mllib

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, prefix

I have sample.txt:

```
1 2 3
1 3 2 1 2
1 2 5
6
```

I need to convert this to feed as input to `prefixSpan` `mllib` `Spark`,

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html

I used

```
val data = sc.textFile("...")
data.map(_.split(' ').map(s => Array(s.toInt)))
```

but I am getting following error, when i run

```
<console>:36: error: inferred type arguments [Nothing,Nothing,org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[Array[String]]]] do not conform to method run's type parameter bounds [Item,Itemset <: Iterable[Item],Sequence <: Iterable[Itemset]]
         val model = prefixSpan.run(sequences)
```